# View Rotation in MonoTouch iPad Application

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios

I'm pretty new to MonoTouch and I'm having problems getting my app to rotate from portrait to landscape mode.

My project has two XIB files, the `MainWindow` added by MonoTouch and `MainController.xib` which I have added. The `MainController` has a single label and no other controls. In my `Main.cs` I have the following to load the `MainController.xib` file:

```
UIViewController controller = new MainController();
window.AddSubview(controller.View);
```

In the `MainController` code I added

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

It all runs fine and the label displays but when I rotate the simulator nothing rotates. I'm sure it's something really simple that I'm getting wrong but I just can't seem to crack it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at TweetStation for a sample.

In this particular case, you might want to return "true" instead of false in the sample above.

Comment: Hi Miguel, sorry for taking so long to mark this as an answer. The TweetStation sample is fantastic as a learning resource and I found the solution in there.